# How to Set Custom DataGridView Headers (with spaces) using LINQ?

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, header

I am populating my DataGridView using LINQ and I would like to have custom headers (which will include spaces).

---

### Wanted Result

This is what my DataGridView headers should look like:

[image: Wanted headers]

---

### Building My DataGridView

```
Private db As New Data.Linq.DataContext("Data Source=SQL01;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True")
Private Articles As Table(Of Article) = db.GetTable(Of Article)()
Private Manufacturers As Table(Of Manufacturer) = db.GetTable(Of Manufacturer)()
Private Providers As Table(Of Provider) = db.GetTable(Of Provider)()

Private Sub btnLoad_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLoad.Click
    Dim allArticles = _
        From a In Articles
        Join m In Manufacturers
        On a.FK_Manufacturer Equals (m.PK_Manufacturer)
        Join p In Providers
        On a.FK_Provider Equals (p.PK_Provider)
        Select Article = a.ArtNum, Description = a.Description, Pièce = a.PartNum, _
                Manufacturier = m.Name, Coût = a.Cost, Fournisseur = p.Name, _
                a.FlagMech, a.FlagStandard, a.FlagAvaible, a.Notes, a.CodeRSPL

    DataGridView1.DataSource = allArticles
End Sub
```

**Current Result**

[image: Current Result]

---

I'm stuck trying to make my headers with only 1 word such as *Article* or *Pièce* instead of **# Article** or **# de pièce**.

I tried doing the following:

```
Select [# Article] = article.ArtNum, ... 'Error; Identifier expected
Or
Select ["# Article"] = article.ArtNum, ... 'Error; Identifier expected
Or
Select "# Article" = article.ArtNum, ... 'Error; Range variable name can be inferred only  from a simple or qualified name with no arguements
```

Is what I'm trying even possible using LINQ?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve. The select clause needs to be valid VB.NET, specifically, the *properties* need to have valid names. `Article` is a property. `# Article` is not a valid name for an identifier.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I'm trying to create descriptive headers for each column in my `Select`. So `Select # Article = article.ArtNum` should equal **# Article** in my DataGridView header

Comment: That's not how it works. The select gets the *data* for your grid. The headers need to come from someplace else.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I see ... If I understand correctly, `Article = article.ArtNum` sets the variable name `Article`. Then the datasource uses the variable names as headers ...

Comment: Correct. The select statement actually creates an anonymous type with one property per "column". The property name is the left side of the assignment. That should make it very obvious that only valid property names are allowed at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I fixed it. I wasn't understanding how the select worked.

The following will set a variable named `Article` to equal `a.ArtNum`

```
Select Article = a.ArtNum
```

---

### How To Set Custom Header Text

Here is how I set my DataGridView  custom headers:

```
DataGridView1.DataSource = allArticles
DataGridView1.Columns("PK").Visible = False
DataGridView1.Columns("ArtNum").HeaderText = "# article"
DataGridView1.Columns("PartNum").HeaderText = "# de pièce"
DataGridView1.Columns("Cost").HeaderText = "Coût ($)"
DataGridView1.Columns("CodeRSPL").HeaderText = "Code RSPL"
```